# How can I call a function by using a variable instead of its name?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Here is my code:

```js
$('.click').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url :  $(this).siblings('a').attr('href'),
        dataType : 'JSON',
        success : function (tags) {
            $("ul").html(tags.output);
        },
        error : function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          if ( textStatus === 'timeout') {
            ajax_error_handleign('timeout error', 10, 5000, 'clear_result_box');
          }
        },
        timeout: 4000
    });
})


function ajax_error_handleign(message, position, aliev_time = 5000, func_name = false){
   if ( func_name !== false ){
      window['clear_result_box']();
   }

   $(".error_msg").html(message);
   $(".error").css({top: position + "px"}).fadeIn(200);
   close_error_msg = setTimeout(function(){ $(".error").fadeOut(100); }, aliev_time);
}

function clear_result_box () {
   console.log('result box is clear now')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='click'>
    click
</button>
```

Also I have `sleep(5);` in the php script that ajax request above refers to. So always `timeout` reaches and `error` will be executed.

**What's the problem?** I get this error:

[image]

Does anybody what's wrong?

Comment: why not just pass the function itself?

Comment: @aw04 Because in your case, I have to call the function multiple times.

Comment: just call it directly then, clear_result_box()

Comment: to answer your question directly, you have the right syntax so it must not be scoped to window, but again.. I think you're trying to be too clever

Comment: I agree you should just call the function. However, if you want to call it that way, just add `window. clear_result_box = clear_result_box;` to the end of your file.

Answer (score 0):

instead of:

```
function clear_result_box () {
    console.log('result box is clear now')
}
```

assign the function to a variable:

```
var clear_result_box = function(){
    console.log('result box is clear now')
}
```

and use the variable after:

```
ajax_error_handleign('timeout error', 10, 5000, clear_result_box);
```

Comment: these are not different enough to affect usage.